# scroll through multiple images in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, scrollbar

I'm writing a script based on tkinter that can display a list of images (here there 3 of them). The goal is to be able to **go through images using the scrollbar position**. These images should not be displayed continuously, but each image is displayed separately.
I searched a lot for this question but it was all about scrolling the images continuously or scrolling big images.

The code I have written so far is as follows, but only the first image appears. And when I scroll, nothing happens.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def nex_img():
    i = scrollbar.get()
    print(i)
    canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor=NW, image=listimg[int(i[0])])  

root = Tk()
image1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('image1.png'))
image2=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('image2.png'))
image3=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('image3.png'))
listimg=[image1,image2, image3]

scrollbar = Scrollbar(master=root, orient=HORIZONTAL) 
scrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
canvas = Canvas(root,width = 800, height = 600,xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set) 
canvas.pack()
scrollbar.config(command=nex_img()) 
root.mainloop()
```

Where I am wrong?

Comment: so You basically want the images in a slide show where similarly one would have to press a button and that would show the next image except You want that with a scrollbar?

Comment: @Matiiss, Yes. Somehow. I just don't want to be able to go to the next image, though. I want the image to be displayed according to the location of the scroll bar. This requires that the number of images is known for the scrollbar. But I do not know how.

Comment: first thing I think You should do is preplace images on canvas, so that they are already there so that the scrollbar can scroll, also don't use `command=nex_img()` because it will call the command once at the start and then use the value it returns which is None so it won't do anything, You can either use `command=lambda: nex_img()` or `command=nex_img` the issue is that it will not show anything in the current code because You have to preplace images instead of placing them dinamically (which can be done but it will be a bit easier to just place them at start)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier with a scale? This way you can set the resolution to 1 and move image by image

Comment: How should I preplace images? Using canvas.create_image? Can it be done in a loop?
Because I might want to display a thousand images by this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue in the code is, as mentioned in the comments,

```
scrollbar.config(command=nex_img())
```

which executes `nex_img` once when executing the code but does not set it as the scrollbar's command since `nex_img()` returns `None`. Therefore it should be replaced by

```
scrollbar.config(command=nex_img)
```

Secondly, since the images will not be scrolled through continuously, I think it is easier to use a `Scale` rather than a `Scrollbar`. In particular, you can set the `resolution` option to 1, the values to go from 1 to `len(listimg)` and the `command` to `nex_img`.

Here is an exammple:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def nex_img(i):   # takes the current scale position as an argument
    # delete previous image
    canvas.delete('image')
    # create next image
    canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor=NW, image=listimg[int(i)-1], tags='image')

root = Tk()
image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('image1.png'))
image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('image2.png'))
image3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('image3.png'))
listimg = [image1, image2, image3]

scale = Scale(master=root, orient=HORIZONTAL, from_=1, to=len(listimg), resolution=1,
              showvalue=False, command=nex_img)
scale.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
canvas = Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)
canvas.pack()

# show first image
nex_img(1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for your prompt solution.